# VueJS splice deletes all item from the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array which I populate using `v-for`. There's also a button, when clicked, deletes some item from the array using `splice()`. However, for some reason, it just deletes all the item of the array.

Here's the code:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    numbers: {
      list: [1, 2, 3],
      index: 0
    }
  },
  computed: {
    getNumbers() {
      let nums = this.numbers.list
      return nums.splice(this.numbers.index, this.numbers.list.length)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sliceOut() {
      this.numbers.index = 1
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="number in getNumbers">
    {{ number }}
  </div>
  <button @click="sliceOut()">Slice</button>
</div>
```

As you can see, instead of getting `[2, 3]`, it is deleting all the items. Please help me fix this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`splice` return the removed elements. So initally when you are calculating the computed property `getNumbers` you are removing all the elements and the removed elements are returned and hence shown in the list rendered using `v-for`.

`splice` also mutates the array and hence the the list is empty now.

Now in further computation, nothing will be return from the `getNumbers` property as the array is blank.

I guess you should use `slice` here instead of `splice` which does not mutates the array.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    numbers: {
      list: [1, 2, 3],
      index: 0
    }
  },
  computed: {
    getNumbers() {
      let nums = this.numbers.list
      return nums.slice(this.numbers.index, this.numbers.list.length)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sliceOut() {
      this.numbers.index = 1
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="number in getNumbers">
    {{ number }}
  </div>
  <button @click="sliceOut()">Slice</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to delete a specific index, write

```
nums.splice(this.numbers.index,1)
```

the second argument of splice function tells how many elements needs to be removed.